# What is wrong with my conditional statement? I'm trying to pull the vowels out

Tags: refactoring

I'm able to get this code to work if I use several if/elsif statements but would like to keep the code neat. Please let me know what is wrong with this code. I was expecting to see an array with ["e"] but returns []

```
def pull_vowels(str)

letters=str.split(//)
vowels=[]

0.upto(letters.count-1) {|idx|
  vowels<<letters[idx]  if letters[idx]==("a"||"e"||"i"||"o"||"u")
}

vowels
end

pull_vowels("test")
```

Comment: You should tag this question with the programming language you're using.

Comment: Also, you should post the code that does work, to help make it clearer what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it's ruby.

Interpreter is not clever enough to understand your intention in `if letters[idx]==("a"||"e"||"i"||"o"||"u")`.

It actually first evals `("a"||"e"||"i"||"o"||"u")` to `"a"`, and then reserves `"a"` only.

You have to specify each case like `if letters[idx]=="a" or letters[idx]=="e" or ...`

Another solution is to use regular expression, like `if letters[idx] =~ /[aeiou]/`

In ruby, you can implement all this more elegently, say

```
def pull_vowels(str)
    str.scan /[aeiou]/
end
```